Does it ever make sense to build a shift register with DRAM cells?
Let's say you have a circuit with a shift register.
You know for a fact this shift register will get a clock signal every tick no matter what happens. There is no clock gate anywhere between the clock source and this register.
Is it ever economical (in size, or power consumption) to build this register out of DRAM cells? If not, why?
The DRAM cells would make the shift register smaller than one built with SRAM cells. Since the stored value is updated every tick, you wouldn't expect to need a refresh cycle with all the associated overhead.
(I'm asking about a shift register, but the broader question applies to any pipelined circuit where registers are only expected to hold values for a single tick.)
Bonus question: what about if the register has a clock gate, but the gate resets the register to zero?

Sounds like what CCDs or dynamic logic already does instead of static logic.


Does it ever make sense to build a shift register with DRAM cells?

Yes. This is how a Charged Coupled Device (CCD) image sensor works. Light falling on pinned diodes affects the charge on an array of capacitors. Afterwards, the charge is shifted toward one edge of the array where they are read. Shifting the charge of all the rows of capacitors to the edge where only one column need be read simplified the design making it feasible to fabricate the CCD.
The invention of the CCD at Bell Labs was awarded the 2009 Nobel Physics prize.

Light does NOT affect the capacitors. The charge comes from photodiodes, the same as most image sensors. The term CCD refers to the method of reading out the pixel data using analog shift registers.

Thanks for pointing that out @DaveTweed. I've adjusted my answer to include Pinned Diode's role in the CCD sensor. I've also found this paper about Pin Diodes and CCDs.

Fairchild had a line of analog shift registers using CCD technology.
Fairchild CCD databook
Look at page 79. They were used as a delay line for NTSC video.

This is really interesting. NTSC is gone, but I believe the color carrier (something notoriously difficult to remove from the brightness signal) was phase shifted 180 every other line. The thought was, technology would eventually catch up and find a way to remove it improving picture resolution. I only read a few paragraphs, but it sure does sound like that was the purpose behind this chip. "A complete TV line of 63.5 uS can be
stored with a sampling frequency of 14.318 MHz (four times color sub-carrier frequency of 3.58 MHz)."

I think it could make sense. There are ASICs used in Karaoke machines that add reverberation and they have a many-stage shift register that delays the sound (in digital form). There's no reason they could not be made using dynamic logic and that would probably reduce the size of the die substantially in a high-volume consumer product. There is no necessity for static SR stages in such an application.

Motorola 68030 minimum frequency says the MC68030 processor used dynamic logic for some blocks, which is why there is a minimum clock frequency. This backs up the suggestion that dynamic logic may be used for a design if a minimum clock frequency is acceptable.

I wish I could mark this comment as the selected answer. "Dynamic logic" is the term I was looking for, and it pointed me towards the concepts I wanted to learn about.

It wouldn't work.
A DRAM does store charge on a capacitor, but you can't directly transfer it from one capacitor to another analogously to how a CCD does it.
in a DRAM, reading the cell erases it because the charge is dumped onto a (highly capacitive) bitline. An amplifier senses this bitline and determined if the value represents a 1 or a 0 (newer DRAMs may store more than 1 bit per cell). The data is then sent to the memory controller and it is rewritten back to the bitcells.
